# My OS update keeps failing, why?

Tags: updates, 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-5

If I go to System Updates in the Settings menu it will start downloading the latest software update. However it invariably fails, and when it does it just says it was unable to download the update but doesn't say why. I've got over 2gb of free space on my phone but I wonder if maybe that's not enough?!
How can I find out why the update won't download? I don't want to just start deleting stuff and making room if storage isn't the issue.

[image]

Comment: Is your phone rooted?

Comment: The phone is not rooted.